# Wine installed but not appearing as an application!

Tags: wine, 20.04, lts, emulation

I have recently installed Wine which is an app for running Windows apps! Wine does not appear in the list of apps and it doesn't appear in the "Open With Another Application" Menu

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ... Wine Version 5.0 ... Installed via "Sudo apt install wine" ... Gnome Shell Version 3.36.2

So how do I use wine if it isn't shown?

Note: This question has been fixed and an answer has been posted!

Answer (score 2):

Wine can be used I just have to run the Wine apps via terminal!

Just type in the name of the wine app you wish to open in the terminal!

Example:

Type this in the terminal "winecfg"